# Error while trying to define a variable inside a tuple or a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to define a variable inside a tuple, but gives me a Syntax Error.

I'm trying to build a small "game" to practice what I have learned.

Here is my code:

```
soldier_sword = (name='Soldier Sword', damage=10, price=25, type_x='attack')
soldier_armor = (name='Soldier Armor', defense=30, price=25, type_x='defense')

gold_dagger = (name='Gold Dagger', damage=15, price=50, type_x='attack')
gold_sword = (name='Gold Sword', damage=25, price=100, type_x='attack')
gold_armor = (name='Gold Armor', defense=50, price=100, type_x='defense')
```

Here is the Error:

```
    soldier_sword = (name='Soldier Sword', damage=10, price=25, type_x='attack')
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried to use lists, but the same error appears.

There is a way to define a variable inside a list or a tuple?

Comment: If you want key/value pairs, use a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this in tuples, use a dictionary instead: `soldier_sword = {'name' : 'Gold Dagger', 'damage' : 15, 'price' : 25, 'type_x' : 'attack'}`

Comment: It is unclear *what you expect that to do*. What is `soldier_sword = (name='Soldier Sword', damage=10, price=25, type_x='attack')` supposed to result in?

Comment: you need to look at `Named Tuples`, you first need to create the "class" for it and use it

Comment: I will try to use dictionarys, thanks! And I will give a look in Named Tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use a tuple/list like that, that's what a **dictionary** is for.

This is what you're supposed to do:

```
soldier_sword = {'name' : 'Soldier Sword', 'damage' : '10', 'price' : '25',
                 'type_x' : 'attack'}
soldier_armor = {'name' : 'Soldier Armor', 'defense' : '30', 'price' : '25',
                 'type_x' : 'defense'}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that you have to put a space in between the variable name and the equals sign, or it will confuse the computer. Try that. I might be wrong though. :P

```
Example_variable = (var = 'put stuff here')
```

Comment: No, its invalid syntax regardless of spaces.